# How to repeat the first element in an array each 2 index

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of arrays:

```
[
  ['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ​​'f', 'g', 'h'],
  ['2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ​​'f', 'g', 'h'],
  ...
]
```

and I need the first element of the arrays to be repeated every 2 positions in each array:

```
[
  ['1', 'a', '1', 'b', '1', 'c', '1', 'd', '1', 'e', ​​'1', 'f', ' 1 ',' g ',' 1 ',' h '],
  ['2', 'a', '2', 'b', '2', 'c', '2', 'd', '2', 'e', ​​'2', 'f', ' 2 ',' g ',' 2 ',' h '],
  ...
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why was the letter "i" left out of the result? Is there a criteria for that or was it a mistake?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. One thing we like to see in questions is some attempt at solving the issue yourself.

Comment: Oh sorry! it was a typing error. It's already edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` and `Array.reduce()`:

```js
let arr = [
  ['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',],
  ['2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',],
]

let res = arr.map(el => {
    let firstEl
    return el.reduce((acc,cur,idx) => {
        firstEl = idx == 0 ? cur : firstEl
        if(idx > 1){
            acc.push(firstEl)
        }
        acc.push(cur)
        
        return acc
    }, [])
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the first element out of the array and take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for the wanted pairs.

```js
const getPaired = ([zero, ...a]) => a.flatMap(v => [zero, v]);

var array = ['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    result = getPaired(array);

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up some kind of for loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++){
    if(i%2 == 0){
        arrayName[i] = arrayName[0];  //puts the first element every 2 index's
    }else{
        //put whatever else needs to be in between
    }
}
```